# Cannot build IOS for bms push Cordova project

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-cloud, push, ibm-mobile-services

I'm not able to build IOS for my cordova project. I have added bms-push plugin and I'm getting error cannot find cannot find module bms core

Answer (score 0):

I was just able to successfully add the `bms-push` plugin and compile a project. Without more detailed error logs and recreation steps, it will be difficult to diagnose your error.

Make sure you have followed the steps in the README here:

https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-cordova-plugin-push/#configuration

---

Installing the `bms-push` library (`cordova plugin add bms-push`) should automatically pull down `bms-core` as a dependency.

Comment: Can you please provide the cordova version you used

Comment: Can you please tell me the exact steps i need to follow

Comment: Hi @nitha, my Cordova version is v6.3.1. I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-cordova-hellopush

Comment: Hi @joe, im using cordova 6.5.0.Is there any problem with this?

Comment: Hi @nitha, if you are experiencing a specific error and can't get the tutorial running, I recommend opening up an issue with the SDK here with a detailed problem description: https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-cordova-plugin-push/issues